# How to transition div on button clicking

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can I transition/animate my div? I was just wanted to do a simple animation like a dropdown menu but can't figure out how :( Thanks for any help!

**Here is the code I'm working with:**

```js
function test1(button) {
   var x = $('#showhide');
   $(button).find('i').remove();
   if ($(button).text().trim() == 'Test') {
     $(button).html($('<i/>',{class:'fas fa-angle-down'})).append(' Test (Hide)');
     x.fadeIn();
    }
    else {
      $(button).html($('<i/>',{class:'fas fa-angle-right'})).append(' Test');
      x.fadeOut();
    }
}
```

```css
.button {
  background-color: #b5b5b5; 
  margin-bottom: 10px; 
  cursor:pointer; 
  border: none; 
  color: #242424; 
  padding: 0px; 
  width: 160px; 
  height: 50px; 
  line-height: 50px; 
  text-align: center; 
  text-decoration: none; 
  display: inline-block; 
  font-size: 16px;
  transition-duration: 0.4s;
}

.button1 {
  background-color: #b5b5b5; 
  color: #242424;
}

.button1:hover {
  background-color: #9c9c9c;
  color: #242424;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/0254f919d5.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<button id="btntest1" onclick="test1(this); if(document.getElementById('test1') .style.display=='none') {document.getElementById('test1') .style.display=''}else{document.getElementById('test1') .style.display='none'}" title="Clique pour en voir +" class="button button1"> 
        <i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i> Test
    </button><br>

<div id="test1" style="display:none; background-color: #b5b5b5; padding: 15px; color: #242424">
<h3>Lorem :</h3>
<ul><li>Ipsum</li><li>dolor</li><li>sit<br></li></ul>

<h3>Nulla :</h3>
<ul><li>id</li><li>mi</li><li>sagittis<br></li></ul>
</div>
```

It is a little bit messy I know but I have just started learning HTML, CSS and Javascript so please don't be rude :(
*(Also I don't speak English very well sorry)*

Comment: try open the console and you will see the error

Comment: The fact that it is a bit messy and that you feel compelled to admit that is a red flag. It means that you should clean things up, and try to isolate the problem. When you're just starting to learn all of this stuff, the most important thing you need to learn is that the cleaner you keep your code, the better things are going to work. If you don't learn this, you're going to keep losing time over problems you can't figure out. Take the time to clean things up and when you run into a problem like this, come up with a minimal case that still exhibits the problem. Then come here and ask :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are already using jQuery, you could use [slideToggle](https://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/) function.

```js
function test1(button) {
  $("#test1").slideToggle("slow");
  var x = $("#showhide");

  $(button).find("i").remove();
  if ($(button).text().trim() == "Test") {
    $(button)
      .html($("<i/>", {
        class: "fas fa-angle-down"
      }))
      .append(" Test (Hide)");
    x.fadeIn();
  } else {
    $(button)
      .html($("<i/>", {
        class: "fas fa-angle-right"
      }))
      .append(" Test");
    x.fadeOut();
  }
}
```

```css
.button {
  background-color: #b5b5b5;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: none;
  color: #242424;
  padding: 0px;
  width: 160px;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  transition-duration: 0.4s;
}

.button1 {
  background-color: #b5b5b5;
  color: #242424;
}

.button1:hover {
  background-color: #9c9c9c;
  color: #242424;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/0254f919d5.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<button id="btntest1" onclick="test1(this);" title="Clique pour en voir +" class="button button1">
      <i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i> Test</button
    ><br />

    <div
      id="test1"
      style="
        display: none;
        background-color: #b5b5b5;
        padding: 15px;
        color: #242424;
      "
    >
      <h3>Lorem :</h3>
      <ul>
        <li>Ipsum</li>
        <li>dolor</li>
        <li>sit<br /></li>
      </ul>

      <h3>Nulla :</h3>
      <ul>
        <li>id</li>
        <li>mi</li>
        <li>sagittis<br /></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using jQuery you can use sildeUp and slideDown, they have built in animation.

```js
  function test1(button) {
            var x = $('#test1');
            $(button).find('i').remove();
            if ($(button).text().trim() == 'Test') {
                $(button).html($('<i/>', { class: 'fas fa-angle-down' })).append(' Test (Hide)');
                x.slideDown();
            }
            else {
                $(button).html($('<i/>', { class: 'fas fa-angle-right' })).append(' Test');
                x.slideUp();
            }
        }
    </script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/0254f919d5.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

```css
.button {
  background-color: #b5b5b5; 
  margin-bottom: 10px; 
  cursor:pointer; 
  border: none; 
  color: #242424; 
  padding: 0px; 
  width: 160px; 
  height: 50px; 
  line-height: 50px; 
  text-align: center; 
  text-decoration: none; 
  display: inline-block; 
  font-size: 16px;
  transition-duration: 0.4s;
}

.button1 {
  background-color: #b5b5b5; 
  color: #242424;
}

.button1:hover {
  background-color: #9c9c9c;
  color: #242424;
}
```

```html
<button id="btntest1"
        onclick="test1(this);"
        title="Clique pour en voir +" class="button button1">
        <i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i> Test
    </button><br>

    <div id="test1" style="display:none; background-color: #b5b5b5; padding: 15px; color: #242424">
        <h3>Lorem :</h3>
        <ul>
            <li>Ipsum</li>
            <li>dolor</li>
            <li>sit<br></li>
        </ul>

        <h3>Nulla :</h3>
        <ul>
            <li>id</li>
            <li>mi</li>
            <li>sagittis<br></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```